# Duplicate an Oracle database user

Tags: oracle

We'll be having external auditors coming over to perform a review on our Oracle database. They will be running a tool to perform the review and for that, they require a user ID that can connect to the database and grab information from it.

We have an existing user in the database for this. However, it is a production ID and we cannot afford to have it locked out. We would like to clone / duplicate this ID including its roles and rights.

Is there a way we can do so in Oracle?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

User creation:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'USER', 'PHIL' ) from dual;
```

Default role:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl( 'DEFAULT_ROLE', 'PHIL' ) from dual;
```

System grants:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl( 'SYSTEM_GRANT', 'PHIL' ) from  dual;
```

Object grants:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl( 'OBJECT_GRANT', 'PHIL' ) from dual;
```

Role grants:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl( 'ROLE_GRANT', 'PHIL' ) from dual;
```

Quotas:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl( 'TABLESPACE_QUOTA', 'PHIL' ) from dual;
```

If any of the above have no output, you'll get an exception that looks something like this:

```
SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl( 'TABLESPACE_QUOTA', 'PHIL' ) from dual;
ERROR:
ORA-31608: specified object of type TABLESPACE_QUOTA not found
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 4018
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 5991
ORA-06512: at line 1

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Then do a search and replace on the output to change the username.

Comment: Note that the DDL generation wraps the existing user in double-quotes; this makes replacing the existing user name very simple.

Comment: The ROLE_GRANT has to precede the DEFAULT_ROLE statement when creating the new user in order to succeed.

Comment: @Theofilos thanks, edited

Answer (score -1):

SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('USER', 'SASIO') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_granted_ddl ('DEFAULT_ROLE', 'SASIO') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_granted_ddl ('SYSTEM_GRANT', 'SASIO') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_granted_ddl ('OBJECT_GRANT', 'SASIO') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_granted_ddl ('ROLE_GRANT', 'SASIO') FROM DUAL

Comment: This looks a lot like the existing answer.